# Bootstrap select dropdown with collapsable sub options

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve bootstrap select drop-down with **collapsible sub options**.

for example : The select drop-down should display the OPTION as **"Vehicle", "House"** etc. where in the option Vehicle will have further sub options as **"2-Wheeler" "3-wheeler" and "4-wheeler"**. These sub-options should be collapsible and only should show when the user clicks on the main option (i.e. Vehicle). And so the user will be able to select only from the sub-options.

Similarly, for the case of **House** - the collapsible sub options should allow user to select any of the options like **"2-BHK","3-BHK","4-BHK"**.

I tried many ways, but couldn't achieve it exactly. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: This link has a lot of details.. Please go through it.

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/bootstrap-menus-navbar-modals

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am seeing many patterns but nothing is matching with this requirement(i.e. A Dropdown with collapsible SUB-OPTIONS). Or in a dropdown, if I can customize a link with the collapsible sub-options, at least ?